# Data Explorer returns "Captcha Shutdown" warning

Tags: support, data-explorer, captcha

I tried to execute [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/710524/most-active-voters-across-the-whole-network) Data Explorer query and instead of the usual Captcha message I got the following:

> [image: V1 SHUTDOWN ON 2018-03-31 Direct site owners to g.co/recaptcha/upgrade]
>   V1 shutdown on 2018-03-31
>   Direct site owners to [g.co/recaptcha/upgrade](https://g.co/recaptcha/upgrade)

Who needs to know about this so the problem can be fixed?

Comment: D'oh! I searched the site for the terms `captcha shutdown` and didn't find anything.

Comment: For small-ish tags, just take a look in the [recently active questions of the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer?sort=active&pageSize=50), no need to search for keywords.